# Multiplication of conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

***Q.***$$ \frac {3}{2+cos\theta+ \iota sin\theta} = a+\iota b $$
**Find** $$ a²+b² $$

***A.*** I took conjugate of both sides giving me -
$$ a-\iota b= \frac{3}{2+cos\theta- \iota sin\theta} $$

Multiplying $$a-\iota b$$ and $$a+\iota b$$,

$$a²+b²= \frac{3}{2+ cos \theta+\iota sin \theta} * \frac {3}{2+cos\theta- \iota sin\theta}$$

***Thus,*** $$ a²+b²= \frac {9}{5+4 cos\theta}$$

The answer given is in terms of 'a'

Answer - $$4a-3$$

Please advise.

Comment: Please use LATEX formatting in your post to make it look neat.

Comment: Please refer to [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some basic $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I was just typing that you should revise my edit to check if the intended meaning was unintentionally changed, but oh well. Your parentheses still look wrong, though.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I whizzed through the tutorial and made changes as best as I could

Comment: What is the answer you're supposed to get?

Comment: I just checked and it looks like we have to take it in terms of 'a' which I don't know how to

Comment: If you can show that $a = \frac{6+3\cos\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}$, then your answer works.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can convert it in terms of 'a'?

Comment: If you mean how to calculate $a$, then yes. Conjugate $\frac{3}{2+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}$, i.e. multiply $\frac{3}{2+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}$ by $\frac{2+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}{2+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}$.

Comment: Conjugating $$ \frac{3}{2+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta} $$ will give me $$ a-\iota b $$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to multiply the term in the denominator by its conjugate. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $ \frac {3}{2+\cos(\theta)+ i \sin(\theta)} = a+i b $

Multiplying top and bottom by $\frac{\cos(\theta)+2-i\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+2-i\sin(\theta)}$ i.e: $ \frac {3}{2+\cos(\theta)+ i \sin(\theta)} \cdot \frac{\cos(\theta)+2-i\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+2-i\sin(\theta)} $

We get $ \frac{3\cos(\theta)+6}{4\cos(\theta)+5}+i\frac{-3\sin(\theta)}{4\cos(\theta)+5}=a+ib$

Hence $a=\frac{3\cos(\theta)+6}{4\cos(\theta)+5}$ and $b=\frac{-3\sin(\theta)}{4\cos(\theta)+5}$

Therefore $$a^2+b^2= \frac{9\cos^2(\theta)+36\cos(\theta)+36}{(4\cos(\theta)+5)^2}+\frac{9\sin^2(\theta)}{(4\cos(\theta)+5)^2}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2= \frac{45+36\cos(\theta)}{(4\cos(\theta)+5)^2} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2=\frac{9(4\cos(\theta)+5)}{(4\cos(\theta)+5)^2}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2=\frac{9}{4\cos(\theta)+5}$$

Which is also equivalent to $4a-3$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\text{c}\space\wedge\space\text{d}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\text{q}\space\wedge\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$, find $|\text{z}|^2=\Re^2[\text{z}]+\Im^2[\text{z}]$:

- $$\frac{\text{c}}{\text{d}+\text{q}}=\text{z}$$

So, we get:

$$|\text{z}|^2=\Re^2[\text{z}]+\Im^2[\text{z}]=\left|\frac{\text{c}}{\text{d}+\text{q}}\right|^2=\frac{\left|\text{c}\right|^2}{\left|\text{d}+\text{q}\right|^2}=\frac{\text{c}^2}{\left(\text{d}+\Re[\text{q}]\right)^2+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$

Now, find the real and imaginary part of $\text{z}$, in terms of $\text{c}$,$\text{d}$ and $\text{q}$:

- $$\Re\left[\text{z}\right]=\Re\left[\frac{\text{c}}{\text{d}+\text{q}}\right]=\frac{\text{c}\left(\text{d}+\Re[\text{q}]\right)}{(\text{d}+\Re[\text{q}])^2+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$
- $$\Im\left[\text{z}\right]=\Im\left[\frac{\text{c}}{\text{d}+\text{q}}\right]=-\frac{\text{c}\cdot\Im[\text{q}]}{(\text{d}+\Re[\text{q}])^2+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$

---

With your information, we get that:

$$\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2=\frac{3^2}{\left(2+\cos(\theta)\right)^2+\sin^2(\theta)}=\frac{9}{5+4\cos(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your calculation was correct and I prefer it to the method used in answer by dydxx. It could be written even more simply in the following way.

Let $w = a + bi$ and let $z =\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$. Then we have $w=\frac 3{2+z}$ and we want to calculate $|w|^2$. Note that $z\bar z=|z|^2 = 1$, so $$|w|^2 = \frac 3{2+z}\cdot \frac 3{2+\bar z} = \frac 9{4 + 2(z+\bar z) + z\bar z} = \frac{9}{5+4\cos\theta}$$

This is the same thing as you did, only written more concisely.

---

The thing that bothers me is how should one go from there to $a^2 + b^2 = 4a - 3$ (which is easy to prove once you know it holds, as I will show later). One could get a hunch that something similar might work from calculation of $a = \frac{6+3\cos\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}$ - same denominator and numerator has only cosine and not sine.

Let us thus try to guess that $a^2 + b^2 = am + n$. Multiplying both sides by $5+4\cos\theta$ we get $$(6+3\cos\theta)m + (5+4\cos\theta)n = 9,$$ i.e. $$ (6m + 5n) + (3m+4n)\cos\theta = 9$$ Now, the right side doesn't depend on $\theta$, so cosines ought to cancel out. We conclude that \begin{align} 6 m + 5n &= 9\\ 3m + 4n &= 0\end{align} and once we solve it, we get $a^2+b^2 = 4a - 3$.

---

If we were told to prove that $a^2 + b^2 = 4a - 3$, there is a neat way to do it without tedious calculations:

$$a^2 + b^2 = 4a - 3 \iff a^2 -4a + 4 + b^2 = 1 \iff (a-2)^2 + b^2 = 1$$

and that is true if and only if $|w-2| = 1$.

Hence,

$$|w-2|^2 = \left|\frac{3}{z+2}-2\right|^2 = \left|-\frac{2z+1}{z+2}\right|^2 = \frac{(2z+1)(2\bar z + 1)}{(z+2)(\bar z + 2)}\\ = \frac{4|z|^2 + 2(z+\bar z) + 1}{|z|^2+ 2(z+\bar z) + 4} = \frac{5+4\cos\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}=1$$ and the statement is proved.